# How to serialize cocos2d hierarchy for save feature

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to create a save game feature in my cocos2d game.
Actually it's kind of a state game, where the game engine is underlying and I built the graphics into a GameLayer (CCLayer) on top of the engine. Actually the game engine is a property of GameLayer.

It's easy to serialize the engine since it ultimately just consists of some raw values, it just takes a bit of `NSCoding` of all contained classes.

However recreating the state of the graphical game seems tough. I am at this moment trying to restore the state by putting things into place upon restore, however this approach is very tedious and extremely prone to mistakes, and takes a lot of time and needs even more time for testing etc. It would be easier if the cocos2d hierarchy would support NSCoding or something similar. I'm thinking I should just add NSCoding to GameLayer as well but is there no simpler way (since the hierarchy should have a finite set of possible children)?

Comment: keep in mind that you can't (easily) serialize scheduled selectors and blocks

Comment: Ok I guess that's the reason why this thing doesn't exist easily. Anyway I kept on with my approach, it took one and a half man days implementing and refactoring, and will possibly take at least a week of internal testing and bad sleep but that's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I carried out my approach with NSCoding... after working out mistakes (some rarely used classes I forgot to NSCoding:ify), it passed testing and the app was sent off to Appstore and is now live. :-P
Kind of a pain in the ass to get this requirement late in a project...